# VBA: How to Add Errors If A Value is Negative or Empty In an Array?

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula, error-handling

I am working on a code from my colleague and I would like to implement it by adding an error when the price of the index is negative or is empty.

In Excel I have this:

[image: Excel spreadsheet]

And I have the following code with my adjustments. However, the function created always shows me `#VALUE!` and not the error I have indicated, probably I am having problems with the iterations. This was my trial:

```vb
Function co(index1 As Range, index2 As Range) As Double
    On Error GoTo error_flag
    
    Dim returns1() As Double, returns2() As Double, i As Integer
    ReDim returns1(index1.Rows.Count - 2) 'resizing the array dynamically
    ReDim returns2(index2.Rows.Count - 2) 'resizing the array dynamically
    
    'PART I ADDED
    For i = 1 To index1.Cells.Rows.Count
        If index1.Cells(i, 1) < 0 Then Err.Raise 1, , "Remove negative prices from Index 1"
        If index2.Cells(i, 1) < 0 Then Err.Raise 2, , "Remove negative prices from Index 2"
        
        If IsEmpty(index1.Cells(i, 1)) Then Err.Raise 3, , "Insert a number in the empy cells for index 1"
        If IsEmpty(index2.Cells(i, 1)) Then Err.Raise 4, , "Insert a number in the empy cells for index 2"
    Next i
    'END OF PART I ADDED
    
    For i = 2 To index1.Cells.Rows.Count
        returns1(i - 2) = Log(index1.Cells(i, 1).Value / index1.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value)
        returns2(i - 2) = Log(index2.Cells(i, 1).Value / index2.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value)
    Next i
    
    co = Application.Covar(returns1, returns2) / Application.StDev(returns1) / Application.StDev(returns2)
    
    Exit Function
    
error_flag:
    co = Err.Description
    
End Function
```

Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: Your function is declared to return a `Double`. You are trying to return a string.

Comment: That's right, thank you!